# Using aggregate function withouhg using GROUP BY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have a script that gathers data from a lot of different tables and pull data as I want. This script is long and very sensitive, if I group by anything we might miss on any data being pulled. Is there a way we can use these functions and not have to Group every single value?

Here is the aggregate functions I am trying to use:

```
CONVERT (INT, ROUND (AVG (CONVERT ( DECIMAL, score)), 0))
```

This part also uses where clause, in simpler script I usually just have a separate select statement to grab this data but in this case it ties into a lot of other LEFT JOINS so I cant put a Where clause as well.

Here is how I am grabbing this field in single script:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT (INT, ROUND (AVG (CONVERT (DECIMAL, score)), 0)) AS AverageScore
FROM 
    tbIDs scm
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIds2 m ON m.ID = scm.ID
WHERE    
    (Score <> 0) AND (m.Complete= 0)
```

How can I have this whole statement in another SELECT query?

For example here is how I want to grab this data within another query

```
SELECT 
    Firstname, LastName,
    CONVERT (INT, ROUND (AVG (CONVERT (DECIMAL, score)), 0)) AS AverageScore
FROM  
    tbppl P 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIds ID1 ON P.PPLID = ID1.PPlID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIDs2 ID2 ON ID1.ID = ID2.ID 
WHERE
    (Score <> 0) AND (m.Complete= 0)
```

When I run it I get an error

> is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an  or the GROUP BY clause.

How can I do this?

Comment: The message seems pretty clear.  You have an aggregation query but no `group by`.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff Yes I know, my questions is that, is there another way of fixing this? I dont want to GROUP by because there is a possibility of it grouping duplicates  which I dont want to, I want to grab absolutely everything.

Comment: Yeah, you're going to need a GROUP BY clause.  That's just how SQL works.  And "miss on any data being pulled"?  I'm not sure what you're concerned about.  You will need to add `GROUP BY Firstname, LastName`.  You're not going to miss any data being pulled--and yes, duplicates will be grouped together, but if they are not, then you have no point in getting an average--how do you average a single score?  You have to have multiple scores to have an average.

Comment: It might be useful to provide some sample data and include an example of a concerned "duplicate".  The problem is probably that you need to refine your WHERE clause or add a HAVING clause.  The GROUP BY is not something you'll be able to bypass.

Comment: "...I want to grab absolutely everything" -- Please provide a few rows of sample data to illustrate what do you think you will lose.

Answer (score 0):

Use `over` and `partition by` instead. It applies the aggregate function while preserving the row structure. The format is as follows:

```
avg(x) over (partition by Group1, Group2, Group3)
```

Given that you want the average over the full data without any "groups", you simply remove the `partition by` part.

Your query (without the data type conversions) is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Firstname, LastName,
    AVG (score) over () AS AverageScore
FROM  
    tbppl P 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIds ID1 ON P.PPLID = ID1.PPlID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIDs2 ID2 ON ID1.ID = ID2.ID 
WHERE
    (Score <> 0) AND (m.Complete= 0)
```

**Edit in response to comment:**

If you want to take the average over a subset of rows subject to a certain condition you need to use the following:

```
avg(case when <conditional logic> then x else null end)
```

If you only want the output rows populated where the condition is met then use:

```
case when <conditional logic> then avg(x) end
```

Combining all of the above for your case gives us:

```
case when (Score <> 0) AND (m.Complete= 0) then avg(case when when (Score <> 0) AND (m.Complete= 0) then Score else null end) over ()
```

Comment: Hi @I_Am_Yohan, is it possible to have this Where clause within the AVG and not apply to the rest of the select statement? right now its even skipping on names whose m.Complete is not equal to 0, I want it to grab the average for those who has scores for those who dont have M.Complete = 0 just leave it empty

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT 
    Firstname, LastName,
    CONVERT (INT, ROUND (AVG (CONVERT (DECIMAL, score)) OVER (PARTITION BY Firstname, LastName), 0)) AS AverageScore
FROM  
    tbppl P 
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIds ID1 ON P.PPLID = ID1.PPlID
LEFT JOIN 
    tbIDs2 ID2 ON ID1.ID = ID2.ID 
WHERE
    (Score <> 0) AND (m.Complete= 0)
```

The difference to your query is the part:

```
OVER (PARTITION BY Firstname, LastName)
```

which your `AVG` invoke lacked.

If you specify more columns when using aggregate functions, you need to use their window alternatives (see [over clause in SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) and in `PARTITION BY` specify additional columns (or use standard `AVG` function and add `GROUP BY` clause).